# That method am I supposed to use here? Recurrence Relations

Tags: recurrence-relations

How am I meant to solve B? I've done A it goes as follows:-

Sequences may be generated by recurrence relations of the form $U_{n+1}=kU_n-20,  U_0=5.$

> A) Show that $U_2=5k^2-20k-20$
>
> B) Determine the range of values of K for which $U_2 \lt U_0.$

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the values of $k$ for which $U_2 < U_0$:

$U_2 < U_0 \Leftrightarrow 5k^2-20k-20 < 5 \Leftrightarrow k^2 -4k-4 < 0$

Do you get how to solve the rest?

Comment: That's a great start, but sadly I don't can you explain further?

Comment: You can assume that $k^2 - 4k - 4 = 0$, then factorise and solve for $k$. The values you will get for $k$ will be the lower and the upper bound of your 'range', lower $k$ will be strictly less than, and upper $k$ will be strictly greater than. Do this: plot $x^2 - 4x -4$, then you will get an idea of which x-values make the expression negative. Does this help?